# Text only launcher Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and I am pretty happy. One of the few things bugging me is that I used <kbd>super</kbd> and then just typing quite a lot for starting software in Ubuntu 14.04.

With Ubuntu 18.04 however, it feels very intrusive to do that: All the windows jump around and I completely lose context.

My question: is it possible to use the search without showing the "Activities" overview?

Maybe there is also a better way to start apps by just typing than using <kbd>super</kbd>?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is like 18.04, this is like that because I think Ubuntu team dev think about Linux newbie and add some "easy" way to start applications with all these icons

Answer (score 1):

Normally I just tap <kbd>super</kbd> key to bring up the search box and application list.

If you don't like that, you can use <kbd>super</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to show the application grid. That's also the place where you can start typing to launch an app from the grid.